# How to implement extended or rich view in material design?

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I want to create scroll layout with one picture, title and text of long article like this one:

http://joxi.ru/BA0vawbfXYZVmy

Requirements on the screenshot:

1. Dynamic scroll with obscuring an image with text view.
2. This little green background with a shadow
3. (optional) transparent status bar

Can anyone tell me what is the best way to do it?
Or at least how does this layout called exactly so I can search and develop further?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are, an [example app](http://antonioleiva.com/materialize-app/) doing in the detail view what you need, with code.